GeoServer installation stuck at 'Granting Access' process
I tried to re-install GeoServer 2.24.3.
I removed it with Uninstall.exe file in Geoserver Folder except Removing 'Geoserver_data'.
And installed GeoServer 2.24.3 the same way.
But Here's what happened. 

Every time I tried to remove and install GeoServer. (I also tried both: automatically(recommended) &  Manually installation), it always stopped at 'Granting Access'.
++plus, I did Executed installer.exe with "Run as administrator" too..
I even waited for two days, but it didn't finish.

I would use a tomcat service and the GeoServer war file - it has much better testing and is probably more stable and faster than running as a windows service

I just solved this by deleting geoserver-data folder.
